# How to run the code more than one time with input Python3

Tags: python

Sorry if the title is unclear.

Let's say I have a code that takes 3 variables, does something with them and then prints the output.
My input would look something like this:

```
1
2
A

output once
```

What I want to do is **paste** **more than 3 variables** in to the terminal/console(sorry i'm not sure what is the proper name) **and expect the code to run more than once**, so it would something like this:
input(pasted):

```
1
2
A

2
2
B

3
3
C
```

and i would like to see something like this:

```
Output for the 1 one
Output for the 2 one
Output for the 3 one
```

Is there a way to do something like this?
If this has been asked before or is easy to find, i'm sorry, i don't really know how to search for this.

Comment: Check out `for loops`

Comment: You should first work through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) if not done yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding while (n) followed by the logic and decrement the count of n inside the while loop

Comment: It still only runs for the first one. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of taking three inputs at a time why don't you take 9 or 11 (including spaces). Then run the same code you had before for the first three, and then the next, and then the next, skipping the spaces.